# Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference (Error when adding strings)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, opencsv

I'm trying to build a simple app that takes in data and outputs it as a CSV.

Everything is working, but now I am at the point where I am outputting the CSV. When I add the string declarations, I get this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference

But when the debugger names my `MainActivity` it references the line my strings begin on. I really have no idea what I'm doing wrong and am admittedly very new to this.

Here is my code:

```
package com.tscmusa.pkelley.gpsform;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ViewFlipper viewFlipper;
    private float lastX;


// File exist


    EditText sub;
    EditText casenumber;
    EditText customer;
    EditText date;
    EditText po;

    String fileName = (sub + "," + date);

    Button btnOk;
    Button btnReturn;

 /*
     String sub = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtSubject)).getText().toString();
    String casenumber = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtCaseNumber)).getText().toString();
    String customer = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtCustomer)).getText().toString();
    String date = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtDate)).getText().toString();
    String po = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPO)).getText().toString();
    String plate1 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPlate1)).getText().toString();
    String boxnumber1 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtBox1)).getText().toString();
    String label1 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtLabel1)).getText().toString();
    String make1 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtMake1)).getText().toString();
    String model1 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtModel1)).getText().toString();
    String year1 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtYear1)).getText().toString();
    String odo1 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtODO1)).getText().toString();
    String vin1 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtVIN1)).getText().toString();
    String notes1 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtNotes1)).getText().toString();
    String plate2 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPlate2)).getText().toString();
    String boxnumber2 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtBox2)).getText().toString();
    String label2 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtLabel2)).getText().toString();
    String make2 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtMake2)).getText().toString();
    String model2 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtModel2)).getText().toString();
    String year2 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtYear2)).getText().toString();
    String odo2 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtODO2)).getText().toString();
    String vin2 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtVIN2)).getText().toString();
    String notes2 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtNotes2)).getText().toString();
    String plate3 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPlate3)).getText().toString();
    String boxnumber3 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtBox3)).getText().toString();
    String label3 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtLabel3)).getText().toString();
    String make3 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtMake3)).getText().toString();
    String model3 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtModel3)).getText().toString();
    String year3 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtYear3)).getText().toString();
    String odo3 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtODO3)).getText().toString();
    String vin3 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtVIN3)).getText().toString();
    String notes3 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtNotes3)).getText().toString();
    String plate4 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPlate4)).getText().toString();
    String boxnumber4 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtBox4)).getText().toString();
    String label4 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtLabel4)).getText().toString();
    String make4 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtMake4)).getText().toString();
    String model4 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtModel4)).getText().toString();
    String year4 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtYear4)).getText().toString();
    String odo4 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtODO4)).getText().toString();
    String vin4 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtVIN4)).getText().toString();
    String notes4 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtNotes4)).getText().toString();
    String plate5 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPlate5)).getText().toString();
    String boxnumber5 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtBox5)).getText().toString();
    String label5 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtLabel5)).getText().toString();
    String make5 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtMake5)).getText().toString();
    String model5 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtModel5)).getText().toString();
    String year5 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtYear5)).getText().toString();
    String odo5 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtODO5)).getText().toString();
    String vin5 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtVIN5)).getText().toString();
    String notes5 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtNotes5)).getText().toString();
    String plate6 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPlate5)).getText().toString();
    String boxnumber6 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtBox5)).getText().toString();
    String label6 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtLabel5)).getText().toString();
    String make6 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtMake5)).getText().toString();
    String model6 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtModel5)).getText().toString();
    String year6 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtYear5)).getText().toString();
    String odo6 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtODO5)).getText().toString();
    String vin6 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtVIN5)).getText().toString();
    String notes6 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtNotes5)).getText().toString();
    String subject = (date + (" ") + sub);
    String fileName = (subject);

*/




    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper);

        sub = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtSubject);
        casenumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCaseNumber);
        customer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCustomer);
        date = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
        po = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPO);

        Intent p1 = getIntent();
       final String plate1 = p1.getStringExtra("pl1");

       Intent bn1 = getIntent();
      final String boxnumber1 = bn1.getStringExtra("bon1");

      Intent lb1 = getIntent();
        final String label1 = lb1.getStringExtra("lbl1");

        Intent ma1 = getIntent();
        final String make1 = ma1.getStringExtra("mak1");

        Intent mo1 = getIntent();
        final String model1 = mo1.getStringExtra("mod1");

        Intent y1 = getIntent();
        final String year1 = y1.getStringExtra("ye1");

        Intent o1 = getIntent();
        final String odo1 = o1.getStringExtra("od1");

        Intent v1 = getIntent();
        final String vin1 = v1.getStringExtra("vi1");

        Intent n1 = getIntent();
        final String notes1 = n1.getStringExtra("no1");

        Button btnOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOK);
        Button btnReturn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReturn);

        btnReturn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                                     {
                                         public void onClick(View v) {
                                             viewFlipper.showPrevious();
                                         }
                                     }
        );

        btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    String content = "Technician" + "," + "Case #" + "," + "Customer" + "," + "Date" + "," + "PO" + "/n"
                            + sub.getText().toString() + "," + casenumber.getText().toString() + "," + customer.getText().toString() + "," + date.getText().toString() + "," + po.getText().toString() + "/n" +
                            "Plate" + "," + "Box Number" + "," + "Label" + "," + "Make" + "Model" + "," + "Year" + "," + "ODO" + "," + "VIN" + "," + "Notes" + "/n"
                            + plate1 + "," + boxnumber1 + "," + label1 + "," + make1 + "," + model1 + "," + year1 + "," + odo1 + "," + vin1 + "," + notes1 + "/n";

                    File file = new File(fileName +".csv");
                    /* if file doesnt exists, then create it */
                    if (!file.exists()) {
                        file.createNewFile();
                    }

                    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                    bw.write(content);
                    bw.close();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });



        if (!isTaskRoot()) {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (intent.hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER) && action != null && action.equals(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)) {
                finish();
                return;
            }
        }




        EditText txtDate = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.txtDate );
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = null;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy/MM/dd" );
        }
        txtDate.setText( sdf.format( new Date() ));

        String[] deviceList = {"Device 1", "Device 2", "Device 3", "Device 4", "Device 5", "Device 6", "Device 7", "Device 8", "Device9", "Device 10", "Device 11", "Device 12", "Device 13", "Device 14", "Device 15"};

        ListAdapter theAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, deviceList);

        ListView theListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.theListView);
        theListView.setAdapter(theAdapter);


        theListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (position==0)
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Device1.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                if (position==1)
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Device2.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                if (position==2)
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Device3.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                if (position==3)
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Device4.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                if (position==4)
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Device5.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                if (position==5)
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Device6.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                if (position==6)
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Device7.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                if (position==7)
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Device8.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                if (position==8)
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Device9.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                if (position==9)
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Device10.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                if (position==10)
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Device11.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                if (position==11)
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Device12.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                if (position==12)
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Device13.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                if (position==13)
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Device14.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                if (position==14)
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Device15.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            }
        });
    }
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent) {
        switch (touchevent.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                lastX = touchevent.getX();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                float currentX = touchevent.getX();

                // Handling left to right screen swap.
                if (lastX < currentX) {

                    // If there aren't any other children, just break.
                    if (viewFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == 0)
                        break;

                    // Next screen comes in from left.
                    viewFlipper.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_from_left);
                    // Current screen goes out from right.
                    viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out_to_right);

                    // Display next screen.
                    viewFlipper.showNext();
                }

                // Handling right to left screen swap.
                if (lastX > currentX) {

                    // If there is a child (to the left), kust break.
                    if (viewFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == 1)
                        break;

                    // Next screen comes in from right.
                    viewFlipper.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_from_right);
                    // Current screen goes out from left.
                    viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out_to_left);

                    // Display previous screen.
                    viewFlipper.showPrevious();
                }
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }








}
```

I've been trying to make this work by transferring the strings from my other classes but to no avail. Here is the example from Device1.class:

```
package com.tscmusa.pkelley.gpsform;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Device1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void BacktoMain(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Device1.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    EditText plate1;
    EditText boxnumber1;
    EditText label1;
    EditText make1;
    EditText model1;
    EditText year1;
    EditText odo1;
    EditText vin1;
    EditText notes1;

    private boolean mMyBoolean;

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        savedInstanceState.putBoolean("MyBoolean", mMyBoolean);
        // ... save more data
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        mMyBoolean = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("MyBoolean");
        // ... recover more data
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_device1);

        plate1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPO);
        Intent p1 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        p1.putExtra("pl1", plate1.getText().toString());
        startActivity(p1);

        boxnumber1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtBox1);
        Intent bn1 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        bn1.putExtra("bon1", boxnumber1.getText().toString());
        startActivity(bn1);

        label1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtLabel1);
        Intent lb1 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        lb1.putExtra("lbl1", label1.getText().toString());
        startActivity(lb1);

        make1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMake1);
        Intent ma1 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        ma1.putExtra("mak1", make1.getText().toString());
        startActivity(ma1);

        model1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtModel1);
        Intent mo1 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        mo1.putExtra("mod1", model1.getText().toString());
        startActivity(mo1);

        year1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtYear1);
        Intent y1 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        y1.putExtra("ye1", year1.getText().toString());
        startActivity(y1);

        odo1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtODO1);
        Intent o1 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        o1.putExtra("od1", odo1.getText().toString());
        startActivity(o1);

        vin1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtVIN1);
        Intent v1 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        v1.putExtra("vi1", vin1.getText().toString());
        startActivity(v1);

        notes1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNotes1);
        Intent n1 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        n1.putExtra("no1", notes1.getText().toString());
        startActivity(n1);

        if (!isTaskRoot()) {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (intent.hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER) && action != null && action.equals(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)) {
                finish();
                return;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Any help would be very greatly appreciated.

Comment: you need to check (MainActivity.java:32) Line 32

Comment: I can give you many recommendation in this class, can you post the whole class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have this initialization here:

```
String vin1 = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtVIN1)).getText().toString();
```

You can declare your variable there like: `EditText vin1;`

And then in onCreate **AFTER** calling setContentView put the initialization like:

```
vin1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtVIN1);
```

Then when you need call `vin1.getText().toString();`

Comment: Thank you very much this helped me greatly, although now I am getting a crash whenever I hit my button assigned 'csv' to create the document. I am creating a new question on here because I've been trying to follow different CSV tutorials for a few days now to no avail.

Comment: Actually, I am unable to create a new question because this is a new account and people have downvoted my current question. It seems reasonable enough to me. If you have noticed anything about my csv export, your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you edit your current post with your full class code. so i can suggest you improvements

Comment: People downvote because it was a silly thing to initiate your Views with declaration, even when they are created after view infated.

Comment: Ah I see. They downvoted because I have no clue what I'm doing, haha. I have updated my code if you are available to help, thank you very much.

Comment: If you have any senior developer, i suggest you show your code to your senior, you seem very new to android. I can optimize your code; you will get the syntax but you will not learn right flow of app,  you made 15 classes, which is not needed, i strongly think. You should learn android basics first.